# Fourier coefficients of $e^{xe^{it}}$

Tags: fourier-analysis

I am given an arbitrary $x \in \mathbb R$ and the $2 \pi$-periodic function $$f(t) = e^{xe^{it}}.$$ The Fourier coefficients are for any $n$ given by
\begin{equation*}
2 \pi c_n ( f)  = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(t)e^{-int}dt
\end{equation*}
This is not very useful as it results in a very ugly integral. Since the function is differentiable on the interval we can use the relation $c(f') = i n c(f)$. The derivative of the function is $ix e^{xe^{it}+it}$ which gives the coefficients:
\begin{equation*}
2 \pi c_n ( f')  = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} ix e^{xe^{it}+it} e^{-int}dt
\end{equation*}
An obvious substitution is $z = xe^{it}$ which gives $x^n \int e^z z^{-n} dz$ but this seems to mess up the integration bounds as $-x = x e^{i \pi} = x e^{- i \pi}$. I therefore tried to find some symmetry in the integrand, but to no avail. Also is this method possible? Do we need to ensure that $f'$ has the same period as $f$? Any hints will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare $f(t)=\displaystyle\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}c_n(f)\mathrm e^{\mathrm int}$ and $\displaystyle\exp(x\mathrm e^{\mathrm it})=\sum_{n\geqslant0}\frac{(x\mathrm e^{\mathrm it})^n}{n!}=\sum_{n\geqslant0}\frac{x^n}{n!}\mathrm e^{\mathrm int}.$

Comment: Well that was obvious! So much for overcomplicating the whole matter I guess ...